# f:ajax restricting the listener method call based on onevent return value

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsf-2, listener

How do i check for Onevent javascript function whether it returns true or False ? Because basically what iam trying to do is to restrict the listener method call based on the Javascript return value .

The following code returns syntax error in Firebug .

```
 <f:ajax event="keyup" render="@form" onevent="return validatePageNumber(event);" listener="#{bean.listenerMethod}"/>
```

So How can i determine return value and based onthat the lister method should fire .Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Bind you component's desired behaviour with "if (!validatePageNumber()) return false;" and enclose within your component tag the f:ajax tag.  That way you'll be able to intercept the execution basing on your JavaScript code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `onevent` attribute must specify a JS function reference name, not a whole JS script. The proper usage of the `onevent` attribute is

```
<f:ajax ... onevent="functionName" />
```

*(yes, without parentheses!)*

with

```
function functionName(data) {
    alert(data.status); // Will show 3 times.
}
```

However, it's clearly the wrong tool for the purpose you had in mind. The `onevent` should merely reference a **listener** function which would be invoked 3 times: one before the ajax request is sent, one after the ajax response is arrived, one after the HTML DOM is updated based on ajax response. For proper real world usage examples, see among others [Proccess onclick function after ajax call <f:ajax>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13540298/proccess-onclick-function-after-ajax-call-fajax/13540905#13540905) and [Disable/enable commandbutton on ajax event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8001068/disable-enable-commandbutton-on-ajax-event/8001153#8001153).

Just use the parent component's `onXXX` attribute instead (where `XXX` is exactly that `<f:ajax event>` you'd like to hook on). E.g. asusming that it's an `<h:inputText>`:

```
<h:inputText ... onkeyup="return validatePageNumber(event)">
     <f:ajax event="keyup" render="@form" />
</h:inputText>
```